# Converting rows into columns based on rank

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rank

I am trying to convert rows into columns based on the customers' purchase date (rank). The goal is to find the first, second, third, fourth, and fifth product category that the customer purchased. I also would like to know what product that the customer purchased.

Sales table

```
purchaseDate | productCategory | product      | customer_id | customer_phonenumber | customer_email
2020-05-05     Electronics       iPhone         A001          1234567890             aoo1@abc.com
2020-05-06     Clothing          T-shirt        A001          1234567890             aoo1@abc.com
2020-05-07     Electronics       Keyboard       A001          1234567890             aoo1@abc.com
2020-05-08     Accessories       iPhone Case    A001          1234567890             aoo1@abc.com
```

Result

```
customer_id | customer_phoneNumber | customer_email | first_product_category | second_product_category | third_product_category | fourth_product_category | fifth_product_category  | first_product | second_product | third_product | fourth_product | fifth_product
A001          1234567890             a001@abc.com     Electonics               Clothing                    Electronics            Accessories               NULL                      iPhone          T-shirt          Keyboard        iPhone Case      NULL
```

I wonder if there is any other way to do this since my current query is taking too long.

Here is my query:

```
with ranked_order as (
    select 
        purchaseDate
        , productCategory
        , product
        , customer_id
        , customer_phonenumber
        , customer_email
        , row_number() over(partition by productCategory order by purchaseDate desc) rank
    from sales_table
    )

    select
        customer_id
        , customer_phonenumber
        , customer_email
        , max(case when rank = 1 then productCategory end) first_product_category
        , max(case when rank = 2 then productCategory end) second_product_category
        , max(case when rank = 3 then productCategory end) third_product_category
        , max(case when rank = 4 then productCategory end) fourth_product_category
        , max(case when rank = 5 then productCategory end) fifth_product_category
        , max(case when rank = 1 then product end) first_product
        , max(case when rank = 2 then product end) second_product
        , max(case when rank = 3 then product end) third_product
        , max(case when rank = 4 then product end) fourth_product
        , max(case when rank = 5 then product end) fifth_product
    from 
        ranked_order
    group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: I'm baffled by what you ware trying to accomplish by this -- I see little use to adding these 10 columns to each purchase record.  Could you provide some sample data and desired results?  And what happens if there are multiple products purchased by the same customer on the same date?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I just edited my question. Hopefully, it gives better context and clarity. I just realized that I made a mistake in my previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  customer_id, 
  customer_phonenumber, 
  customer_email,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].productCategory AS first_product_category,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].productCategory AS second_product_category,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(2)].productCategory AS third_product_category,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(3)].productCategory AS fourth_product_category,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(4)].productCategory AS fifth_product_category,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].product AS first_product,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].product AS second_product,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(2)].product AS third_product,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(3)].product AS fourth_product,
  top5[SAFE_OFFSET(4)].product AS fifth_product
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, customer_phonenumber, customer_email,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(productCategory, product) ORDER BY purchaseDate LIMIT 5) AS top5
  FROM `project.dataset.sales_table`
  GROUP BY customer_id, customer_phonenumber, customer_email
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put the values in arrays:

```
select customer_id, customer_phonenumber, customer_email,
       array_agg(productCategory order by purchaseDate limit 5) as productCategorys_5,
       array_agg(product order by purchaseDate limit 5) as products_5
from sales_table
group by 1,2,3
```

This puts the values in arrays rather than columns.  If this has good-enough performance, you can just index the arrays to get in the individual elements (although I might find the arrays to be more convenient).